Lie algebra question about the highest weight of a root system
I'm reading the book James E. Humpreys's book Introduction to Lie algebras and Representation Theory .
In this book the section 13.4 said in case $\Phi$ is irreducible, there is a unique highest root (relative to a fixed base
$\Delta$ of $\Phi$ )(Lemma 10.4A), so $\Pi$ has this root as its highest weight.
So my question is why in this case the highest root is the highest weight? Couldn't we find another weight $\mu$, which is not a root, and the highest root $\lambda$ such that $\mu \succ \lambda$ so that the $\mu$ is the highest root?
I would appreciate for any help!

There can't be any other weights in $\Phi$ by definition. He chooses it to be the set of roots together with $0$.
In effect, Humphreys is using the adjoint representation as an example where the weights are exactly the roots (and $0$ which is not usually counted as a root but is a weight).

That is SO TRUE, Thank you :) I think I misunderstood the context.
